# how to insert current system date with spring data mongodb?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

i try with this

```
public void setDate(Timestamp date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = calendar.getTime();
    Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(now.getTime());
    this.date = currentTimestamp;
}
```

and when i try request the list of objet that contains date from postman i get this error No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.Date] to type [java.sql.Timestamp]

Comment: java version that you are using? If 8 there are simpler ways to do this... assuming some ORM is in place

Comment: use `java.sql.Date`

Comment: Use java 8 `LocalDate` and `LocalDate.now()`

Comment: it 's working and it 's apear like this ISODate("2017-04-09T22:00:00Z") and why the " 22:00:00Z" is inchangeable i want the date with h/m/s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDb saves the date in UTC.

You should use `java.time.Instant` with spring mongodb provider on Java 8

You can use  `Instant instant = timestamp.toInstant();` to convert to instant and pass this to spring mongodb provider on java 8.

You should use `java.util.Date` with spring provider on Java 7.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: it works but there is 1 hours difference between the sys date and the date displayed 2017-04-10T14:36:52.547Z and it should be 2017-04-10T15:36:52.547Z there is a solution ?

Comment: is 1 hour your timezone offset from utc ? If yes that is expected and correct as MongoDb saves date in UTC.

Comment: God bless for Java 8 and Instant.now()

Answer (score 1):

Insert your date in MongoDB using the code below:

`new Date(actiondate.getTime() - (actiondate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000))`